# Run yum updates but exclude certain modules/libraries/packages

Tags: centos, ansible

I'm trying to use Ansible to upgrade our Centos 6.5 and 7.0 servers but exclude certain updates.  For instance...

One server has two different packages we never want to update since it'll mess with our developers:

- elasticsearch-5.6.8-1
- kibana-5.6.8-1

Everything else we would like to update.  I'm using those as examples of what to not update on only those 2 servers running 7.0.  However, there are other instances where we would like to update everything except maybe a handful of applications or modules like above.

This is what I'm using for my yum update playbook.  It works fine but updates everything that's available for updating.

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: update OS
      yum: name=* state=latest
      remote_user: root
```

any help's appreciated.

Comment: https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/exclude-specific-packages-yum-update/

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. Did you mean to ask at [sf]?

Answer (score 4):

`yum` module has an `exclude` parameter. Add it to your code:

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: update OS
      yum:
        name: "*"
        exclude:
          - elasticsearch
          - kibana
        state: latest
```

Answer (score 0):

The yum module does have the ability to exclude packages using the exclude attribute.

However, in your case, it would be better practice to exclude the packages from the yum repository. See the [yum_repository](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_repository_module.html) module for details.

Comment: "*The yum module does not have the ability to exclude packages*" -- really?

Comment: Whoops, I am blind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exclude` on the yum module https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html but, like @aaron-walker, I would disable all the repos, for those rpms that you don't want to update to have extra assurance that they won't be updated using `disablerepo`.